# To have a date picker to show on multiple worksheets in the same columns

Tags: excel, vba, datepicker

I add a date picker 12.0 on Sheet 1 and would like to have it working across sheet 2 and sheet 3 as well.

The below code only works on column 3 and column 6 of sheet 1, but when I click on the column 3 and column 6 in sheet 2 or sheet 3, no date picker shows up.

Please help, thanks a bunch!

```
Private Sub Calendar1_Click()
Selection.Value = Calendar1.Value
Calendar1.Visible = False
Calendar1.Value = Date
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column <> 3 And Target.Column <> 6 Then Calendar1.Visible = fales: Exit Sub
Calendar1.Top = (Target.Row - 1) * 16.5

Calendar1.Top = ActiveCell.Top 
Calendar1.Left = ActiveCell.Left + 80

Calendar1.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Where and how is Calendar1 declared? Is this a userform for the date picker? I think this would simply need to have your event changed from the worksheet to the workbook trigger. But depends if your code can reference Calendar1 accross all sheets.

Comment: The first calendar is inserted in Sheet1 by using the insert other object function under the developer tab.

Comment: I sadly have 64 bit Excel so can't test that control. You can try macro recording as you manually add a Date Picker control to a sheet. Then you can in VBA replicate adding the object to each sheet using code. For example to add and Equation object you would `ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Equation.3", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False).Activate`. Find how this works for adding date picker and customize to your use.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in `Workbook` Module

Option Explicit

```
Private Sub Calendar1_Click()
    Selection.Value = Calendar1.Value
    Calendar1.Visible = False
    Calendar1.Value = Date
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column <> 3 And Target.Column <> 6 Then
    Calendar1.Visible = False
    Exit Sub
Else

  Calendar1.Top = (Target.Row - 1) * 16.5
  Calendar1.Top = ActiveCell.Top
  Calendar1.Left = ActiveCell.Left + 80
  Calendar1.Visible = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the reply! I pasted the code in TheWorkbook module instead of in sheet1 as shown but nothing happened. I then pasted the code in sheet 2 and 3 and a "424 error object required" prompted, it seems I have to insert a date picker for each sheet?

Comment: Thanks for the updated code; however, the error is still the same. This error prompts across all three sheets, regardless where I click. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Calendar1 is available to the other worksheets then include your event trigger in the `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange` as below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column <> 3 And Target.Column <> 6 Then Calendar1.Visible = False: Exit Sub
    Calendar1.Top = (Target.Row - 1) * 16.5

    Calendar1.Top = Target.Top
    Calendar1.Left = Target.Left + 80

    Calendar1.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Regards,